# How can i connect my domain (godaddy) to my EKS ALB

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have successfully installed and ingress into my EKS cluster and all its dependancies such as the AWS Load Balancer Ingress Controller, ServiceAccounts and the rest of them.

I have also applied the manifest below which has created an application load balancer i can see in my console with the right target. It points to the right service. Now my issue is i bought my domain on Godaddy, and previously i'd create a classic Loadbalancer and attach an Elastic IP to that load balancer then add that EIP address to my Godaddy DNS record and that would work and that would route my domain name to the classic elb.

Now i am trying to route through an alb.

**Ingress Manifest**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing0-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ui0-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

The image below shows the ALB in the console.

[image]

I can also see the target has been picked up properly.

[image]

however when i copy the DNS name of that ALB into the browser, i do not get anything returned. I am expecting to see a site which one of my network load balancer is pointing to through a pod deployment. I am able to paste the network load balancer DNS name to the browser and see a site. I expect that since the ingress is deployed correctly, it should route to that same network load balance through one of the ingress paths.

so for instance let's say this is the ingress dns name `k8s-ingXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` ... i expect that this should route me to example.com... Also how do i map my Godaddy domain name to this ingress.

Answer (score 0):

You can only  add alias(A) record for top level domain. There are two possible ways to solve your issue.

1. Use nginx ingress controller instead of AWS load balancer controller. Nginx ingress controller can create NLB for your service. Which will have a static ip. (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)
2. Use Route53 hosted zone as DNS server for your domain. Basically you need to replace GoDaddy nameservers with AWS Route53's name server. Then you can use Alias record.(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-create-alias-records/)